# Firefox - log of which files (CSS / JS / images) returned a 404 error?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a rather hectic situation in which my client has given me a bunch of files and said to put them all on the server and link to the main CSS files only. These in turn use @import and alike. The page does not look much like they think it should. Does anyone know where I can find a log of which requests (to CSS / JS / image files) returned a 404 and which ones were found, or tell me what extension to install to give me a list of files? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Firebug's](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) net panel.

Comment: Marked as correct answer since a) I like giving out points, rather than marking my own as answer and giving out no points and b) the pages I used HTTPFox on mucked up after a couple of page loads..

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome.  Go to the spanner and click Tools > Developer Tools.  In the resultant panel at the bottom of your window go to Resources.  Fire in your request.  Look at the bottom right for a red cross.  Click it.  This will show all your 404s.

Comment: Thanks. I just found an addon for Firefox having suddenly thought of the key phrase - HTTP Requests. The advantage of using Firefox is that we don't support Chrome but do support Firefox so there is no need to have two browsers open. I will post an answer in a mo.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found an addon called HTTPFox. It seems pretty good and tells me exactly what the result is for each file. It does exactly what I need it to do without the need to open another browser.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Richard